# smoothing array and keep the array length unchanged in Scala

Tags: scala

I have an array smoothing function like that:

```
def smoothArray(rawdata:Array[Double], window:Int):Array[Double] = {

      rawdata.sliding(window).map(_.sum/window).toArray

}
```

It works, however, the output array size is not the same as the input array size. This is because the sliding function generates only the groups with `window` size.

Is there anyway to output the same size array as input? Even use the same data points? For example, for

```
val input = Array(1,2,4,9,14)
val window = 3
```

output looks like:

```
(1, 2.33, 5, 9, 14)
```

Or better way if anyone could come up with?

Comment: So for 3 elements, you would pick (1, smooth, 14), and for larger Arrays and larger window? For Arrays of even size? Formulize your rules, and try to implement them. Maybe an outer/inner Function is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify how you want to deal with the boundary conditions.
From your example I've inferred that you want to keep the values on the boundary
fixed (`1` and `14` remained unchanged).

Here is a smoothing operation that produces arrays of same size and preserves
the boundary conditions:

```
def smoothArray(rawdata:Array[Double], window:Int):Array[Double] = {
  require(window % 2 == 1, "The kernel should be symmetrical, only windows of uneven size allowed")
  val leftBoundary = rawdata.head
  val rightBoundary = rawdata.last
  val truncatedHalfKernelWidth = window / 2 // must be integer division!
  val leftPadding = Array.fill(truncatedHalfKernelWidth)(leftBoundary)
  val rightPadding = Array.fill(truncatedHalfKernelWidth)(rightBoundary)
  val res = (leftPadding ++ rawdata ++ rightPadding).sliding(window).map(_.sum/window).toArray
  // restoring the boundary conditions
  res(0) = leftBoundary
  res(res.size - 1) = rightBoundary
  res
}
```

Here is your example:

```
/* first tiny example */ {
  val input = Array[Double](1,2,4,9,14)
  println(smoothArray(input, 3).map(x => "%1.2f".format(x)).mkString(","))
  println(smoothArray(input, 5).map(x => "%1.2f".format(x)).mkString(","))
  println(smoothArray(input, 7).map(x => "%1.2f".format(x)).mkString(","))
}
```

Here is the output for your example:

```
1.00,2.33,5.00,9.00,14.00  // w = 3
1.00,3.40,6.00,8.60,14.00  // w = 5
1.00,4.57,6.43,8.29,14.00  // w = 7
```

What's funny about this smoothing operation is that it solves the heat equation if you 
iterate a few times. Here is an extended example with a larger array with more interesting 
initial values (forgive me the ugly ascii graphics, running this from console):

```
/* More interesting iterative example */ {
  def drawArray(arr: Array[Double], yRange: Range): Unit = {
    val width = arr.size
    val visibleHeight = 20
    val canvas = Array.fill(visibleHeight, width)(' ')
    for (i <- 0 until width) {
      val y = arr(i)
      val barHeight = (visibleHeight * (y - yRange.min) / yRange.size).toInt
      if (barHeight > 0) {
        for (j <- 0 until (barHeight min visibleHeight)) {
          canvas(visibleHeight - j - 1)(i) = '#'
        }
      }
    }
    for (row <- canvas) println(row.mkString)
  }

  val initialArray = Array.tabulate(80){ x => 
    val linearTerm = x * 1000 / 80
    val parabolicTerm = x * (79 - x)
    val sineTerm = math.sin(x / 80.0 * math.Pi * 4)
    val randomTerm = math.random * 1000
    linearTerm + (if (x != 0 && x != 79) {
      parabolicTerm + sineTerm + randomTerm
    } else 0.0)
  }

  var smoothed = initialArray
  for (iter <- 0 until 10000) {
    if (iter < 10 || (iter < 2000 && iter % 100 == 0) || iter % 1000 == 0) {
      println("iter " + iter)
      drawArray(smoothed, 0 to 3000)
    }
    smoothed = smoothArray(smoothed, 5)
  }

}
```

It starts with a mix of

- a constant linear slope
- parabolic bulge in the middle
- low-frequency sinusoidal oscillation
- random noise

-

```
iter 0

                                        #  #    #      #                        
                                #   ### #  ## # #      #    #                   
                                #   ### # ### # #      ##   #                   
                            #   #   ### # ##### ##    ###   ### # ##            
                    #       #   ## ###############  ######  ### # ##    #       
                    #     # #  ### ############################ #####   #       
                  # #     # ## ################################ #####   ##  #   
               #  # #    ############################################   ##  # # 
              ## ####  ######################################################## 
             ### #### ######################################################### 
            #### ############################################################## 
        #  #################################################################### 
     #  ####################################################################### 
     # #########################################################################
     ###########################################################################
 #  ############################################################################
 # #############################################################################
 # #############################################################################
 ###############################################################################
```

Within a few iterations, it kills high-frequency noise:

```
iter 1


                                          # #                                   
                                     ###########                                
                                  #################  #####                      
                              #####################################             
                              ######################################            
                          ###########################################     #     
                   ## # ####################################################    
               ###############################################################  
             ################################################################## 
            ################################################################### 
          ##################################################################### 
       ######################################################################## 
      ##########################################################################
     ###########################################################################
   #############################################################################
   #############################################################################
 ###############################################################################
 ###############################################################################
iter 5



                                      ##########                                
                                  ########################                      
                               ##################################               
                             #######################################            
                          #############################################         
                      ####################################################      
                ############################################################    
              ###############################################################   
            ##################################################################  
          ##################################################################### 
        ####################################################################### 
       #########################################################################
     ###########################################################################
    ############################################################################
   #############################################################################
  ##############################################################################
 ###############################################################################
```

Then it mostly smoothes out the sinusoidal oscillation, until we are left with a 
squashed version of the parabolic bulge:

```
iter 200






                                          #######                               
                                  ########################                      
                             ##################################                 
                          ########################################              
                       ###############################################          
                    #####################################################       
                 ###########################################################    
               ################################################################ 
             ###################################################################
          ######################################################################
        ########################################################################
      ##########################################################################
    ############################################################################
  ##############################################################################
```

The parabolic term gets smaller and smaller...

```
iter 700












                                      ############################              
                              ##############################################    
                         #######################################################
                    ############################################################
               #################################################################
           #####################################################################
        ########################################################################
    ############################################################################
```

Until everything is completely "smoothed" into a straight line between the two
boundary conditions:

```
iter 9000














                                                                         #######
                                                             ###################
                                                 ###############################
                                     ###########################################
                        ########################################################
            ####################################################################
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Interesting, and I would accept this. However, there is a tiny thing need to be handle further. Insert 1 element before and after filter is just for the case window = 3. If window = 5, it is necessary to more elements.

Comment: It works with windows of arbitrary length (well... should be positive uneven int, the resulting arrays should fit into memory).